# How to include a pdf link in react.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, react-router, reactjs

i want to be able to open in a new tab a PDF i have in my include folder. I'am using the create-react-app and set the link to open a new tab with the pdf, in my local it works but when i build it the tab loads as an empty page with a HTTP ERROR 404.

in my react component here is how i had it set up

```
<NavLink to={PDF} target='_blank' className='nav-link'>pdf</NavLink>
```

like i mentioned before in my local it works perfect but in my build it opens a 404 page.

Comment: where is this pdf uploaded?Is it some dropbox or drive link?

Comment: @VivekN it's setup in a include folder within my src folder.

Comment: what is the value of {PDF} that you see in production build?

Comment: <a href={PDF} target='_blank' className='nav-link'>pdf</a>

Comment: @VivekN sorry what do you mean as in value?

Comment: You must be having some link for the variable PDF Right.What is that url.I want to check how is it defined.Is it relative or absolute?

Comment: @IgorStecyura that wouldn't really fix anything

Comment: @VivekN i have it as an imported file

import pdf from '../etc'

when it renders in my local i get PDF.fb071a8c.pdf but on my build it's 404

Answer (score 0):

> like i mentioned before in my local it works perfect but in my build it opens a 404 page.

This is a server error.

## Find out whats wrong

- Log the URL
- Check the browser console for failed web requests

## Fix

Once you have the URL check why there isn't a file at that URL.